# Calculating average time difference across rows and two groups

Tags: sql, netezza

I have a table that resembles the following. This is a data from an urgent care center, with the ROOMED_DT being when a patient is given a room, and the CHECKOUT_DT being the time the patient is cleared to leave:

```
PAT_ID     ROOMED_DT              CHECKOUT_DT          ROOM_NUM
1          11/12/2015 03:22PM     11/12/2015 06:30PM   Room 4
2          11/12/2015 07:40PM     11/12/2015 10:30PM   Room 4
3          11/12/2015 10:55PM     11/12/2015 11:30PM   Room 4
4          11/12/2015 09:45AM     11/12/2015 12:00PM   Room 5
5          11/12/2015 12:02PM     11/12/2015 01:30PM   Room 5
6          11/12/2015 02:25PM     11/12/2015 04:30PM   Room 5
7          11/13/2015 07:22AM     11/13/2015 08:04AM   Room 2
8          11/13/2015 09:40AM     11/13/2015 10:30AM   Room 2
9          11/13/2015 10:55AM     11/13/2015 11:55AM   Room 2
10         11/13/2015 12:45PM     11/13/2015 02:00PM   Room 1
11         11/13/2015 04:02PM     11/13/2015 05:30PM   Room 1
12         11/13/2015 05:25PM     11/13/2015 08:30PM   Room 1
```

I would like the calculate the average time from when the previous patient is cleared to leave (CHECKOUT_DT) to when the next patient appears (ROOMED_DT) for each room, on each day, so the result would look something like this (I'm making the average numbers up, for the sake of the visual), with the time to the next patient being in minutes.

```
SERVICE_DT     TIME_TO_NEXT_PAT
11/12/2015     65.7
11/13/2015     72.4
```

But I'm not sure how to account for the difference between CHECKOUT_DT and ROOMED_DT across multiple patients and multiple rooms. Does anyone have any ideas? I'm using Netezza.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lead` analytic function to get these results.

here is the query

```
SELECT SERVICE_DATE
, AVG(MINUTES_BETWEEN) 
FROM (
        SELECT PAT_ID
        , ROOMED_DT::DATE SERVICE_DATE
        , ROOMED_DT
        , CHECKOUT_DT
        , ROOM_NUM
        , LEAD(ROOMED_DT,1) OVER (PARTITION BY ROOM_NUM ORDER BY ROOMED_DT) NEXT_CHECKED_IN
        , MINUTES_BETWEEN(NEXT_CHECKED_IN,CHECKOUT_DT) 
        FROM SAMPLE 
        ORDER BY 1
) FOO 
WHERE MINUTES_BETWEEN IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY 1;

 SERVICE_DATE |    AVG
--------------+-----------
 2015-11-12   | 38.000000
 2015-11-13   | 62.000000
(2 rows)
```